# Using Ansible Callback, can I extract the YAML code of task currently run?

Tags: ansible

Using a custom Ansible Callback, I want to extract the YAML code of the task currently run : I guess I should use `v2_playbook_on_task_start` which is called for each task.

```
    def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task: BaseMeta, is_conditional: bool):
```

Can I get the YAML code used to define the task ?

Comment: Have you checked how [other callback plugins do it](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara/blob/1.5.6/ara/plugins/callback/ara_default.py#L249)?

Comment:  Thank you, I was able to get the playbook content using this example. I will test with others use cases (roles and playbooks imports) and add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ara Callback : https://github.com/ansible-community/ara/blob/1.5.6/ara/plugins/callback/ara_default.py#L249

Define these two variables in the **CallbackModule** class :

```
    self.file_cache = {}
    self.ignored_files = []
```

Add this logic to the function **v2_playbook_on_task_start** :

```
def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task, is_conditional):

    pathspec = task.get_path()
    if pathspec:
        path, lineno = pathspec.split(":", 1)
        lineno = int(lineno)
    else:
        # Task doesn't have a path, default to "something"
        path = self.playbook["path"]
        lineno = 1

    # Get task file
    task_file = self._get_or_create_file(path)
    print(task_file)
```

Define **_get_or_create_file** function :

```
def _get_or_create_file(self, path, content=None):
    if path not in self.file_cache:
        display.v("File not in cache, getting or creating: %s" % path)
        for ignored_file_pattern in self.ignored_files:
            if ignored_file_pattern in path:
                display.v("Ignoring file {1}, matched pattern: {0}".format(ignored_file_pattern, path))
                content = "Not saved by ARA as configured by 'ignored_files'"
        if content is None:
            try:
                with open(path, "r") as fd:
                    content = fd.read()
            except IOError as e:
                display.v("Unable to open {0} for reading: {1}".format(path, str(e)))
                content = """ARA was not able to read this file successfully.
                        Refer to the logs for more information"""
    return content
```

---

This will return the following statement :

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
File not in cache, getting or creating: /Users/foo/bar/plays/playbook.yml
---
- name: Call the callback plugins
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    output: a

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: test

  - name: assert that output is a
    assert:
      that: output == 'a'
      msg: output does not equal a
    register: assert_register

ok: [node2] => {
    "test": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'test' is undefined"
}
ok: [node3] => {
    "test": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'test' is undefined"
}

TASK [assert that output is a] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
File not in cache, getting or creating: /Users/foo/bar/plays/playbook.yml
---
- name: Call the callback plugins
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    output: a

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: test

  - name: assert that output is a
    assert:
      that: output == 'a'
      msg: output does not equal a
    register: assert_register

ok: [node2] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}
ok: [node3] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
node2                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
node3                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```